# agrego extends ListActivity y el emulador me bota error

Tags: android

no me muestra el layout al compilarlo. y me sale el error típico cuando no agregas la actividad en el manifest. ya hice las pruebas, el error se genera cuando agrego el ListActivity ya que estoy usando un listview.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.vistony.newapp, PID: 32006
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vistony.newapp/com.vistony.newapp.View.ConsDespachocActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
        at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:293)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
        at com.vistony.newapp.View.ConsDespachocActivity.onCreate(ConsDespachocActivity.java:43)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: por favor cuando preguntes sobre un error agrega que error es desplegado en el LogCat o la consola. Además en este caso es importante agregues tu código ya que comentas "el error se genera cuando agrego el ListActivity" , edita tu pregunta o la pueden cerrar. Saludos! =)

Answer (score 1):

El problema se describe aquí:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a
>   ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

De hecho acabo de ver que extiendes tu `Activity` de `ListActivity`, en este caso no deberías usar `setContentView()`

Si deseas usar `extends ListActivity`, entonces obtén la referencia del `ListView` de esta forma:

```
ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

y no deberias usar `setContentView()`

Encontré un ejemplo [aquí](https://nickcharlton.net/posts/building-custom-android-listviews.html) de lo que deseas `extends ListActivity`, revisa HelloListView.java.

```
public class HelloListView extends ListActivity {
    //define el data source
    private ArrayList<String> data;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // configura data source
        this.data = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Agrega algunos objetos.
        this.data.add("List Item 1");
        this.data.add("List Item 2");
        this.data.add("List Item 3");

        // use el layout archivo .xml 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Configura el adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.text, this.data);

        // specify the list adaptor
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: la solución es mapear el listview como dijiste @Elenasys. Luego le añadí las siguientes propiedades al listview (donde lo que está en negrita es importante):




        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            **android:id="@android:id/list"** />

Comment: Que bien, Pueden ser ambas opciones, me parece que es más común extender de Activity y agregar el elemento llistview con su respectivo id dentro del Layout.